# WP Settings API save to multiple options

Tags: wordpress, settings, admin

In the Wordpress Settings API, creating a new options page usually starts out with

```
register_setting('sample_options', 'my_option');
add_settings_section('section', 'Sample Options', 'callback1', 'page');
add_settings_field('name', 'Label', 'callback2', 'page', 'section');
```

In this simplified example, the data gets saved in the option `my_option` making the value of *name* accessible through

```
$option = get_option('my_option');
$name = $option['name']; // Got it
```

But what if the value of the *name* field is there not to place a new value but to update an already existing option that's not `my_option` like for example `this_other_option`? I guess what I'm really looking for is is it possible for one field to save to multiple options (`my_option` and `this_other_option`) while using the Settings API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you could use a callback in `register_setting`. It would look something like the following:

```
<?php
register_setting('sample_options', 'my_option', 'my_sanitize_callback');

function my_sanitize_callback($value, $option) {
    $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    update_option('my_other_option', $value);
    return $value;
}
?>
```

You may have to tweak that a bit. I haven't tested it.

Comment: That worked! The answer was staring at me right in the face. Thanks Rob.